# How to force a Powershell Script to run a specific Version

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-core

I have both PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.0 on my computer.  How can I enforce a mandatory version (a *specific* version, not a minimum or maximum version #) of PowerShell for a given script (in this case, PowerShell 7.0)?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but also can help. [`Requires` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires) can prevent running the script in a lower PS version.

Answer (score 6):

another option is to use #Requires statement

```
#Requires -Version 7.0
```

here is the reference from Microsoft support

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires

Answer (score 4):

If it's a script being invoked in a PS shell, you could relaunch it if it's not the correct version.

```bsh
# At beginning of .ps1
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -ne [Version]"5.1") {
  # Re-launch as version 5 if we're not already
  powershell -Version 5.1 -File $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
  exit
}

# Your script code
```

---

If the scripts are launched via Task Scheduler, you could just use the full path to the .exe in the "Actions -> Start a program" section, as they have separate install locations.

[image: Schedule task]