# Can we call a runbook from another runbook in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I'm having two runbooks of two different Powershell versions (5.1, 7.1). How to call a runbook (7.1) from runbook (5.1)?

Modules used:

1. AZ-SecurityInsights - 5.1 version (runbook 5.1)
2. AzSentinel - 7.1 version (runbook 7.1)

Need to pass resourcevariable as an input parameter to second runbook from first runbook.

My code:

```
 $AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName  $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext  
Start-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName -Name "ExportAlertRule" -ResourceGroupName $automationResourceGroupName
```

Error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What can I try next?

Comment: Powershell is located in following folder : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell.  If you have two version of powershell installed they should be in a subfolder.

Comment: Actually using automation account of azure. From there created two runbooks of different versions and trying to call one from other

Comment: Use something like this : powershell -Version 5.1 -File $MyScript

Comment: Can u provide a sample if possible ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720842/how-to-force-a-powershell-script-to-run-a-specific-version

Answer (score 0):

If the output stream of Start-AzAutomationAccount contains object, the command does not process the output stream correctly. For the same, you need to implement a polling logic, and use the Get-AzAutomationJobOutput cmdlet to retrieve the output.

For more information, refer below documents.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/runbooks#resolution-13
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-child-runbooks#runbook-types