# How to overcome WARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 2?

Tags: json, powershell, azure-automation

I have provided my code and JSON format below. I'm using Powershell runbook to retrieve the values from this json. But I am facing error. How can I fix it?

**My JSON:**

```
{"hunting": [
  {
    "displayName":"New Changes made to AWS IAM policy", 
    "description":"test",
    "query":"SecurityEvent | where EventID == \"4687\" | where CommandLine contains \"-noni -ep bypass $\"",
    "tactics":["Persistence","LateralMovement","Collection"]
  },{
    "displayName":"New Consent to Application discovery",
    "description":"test",
    "query":"SecurityEvent | where EventID == \"4688\" | where CommandLine contains \"-noni -ep bypass $\"",
    "tactics":["Persistence","LateralMovement"]
   }
]}
```

**My code:**

```
Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Destination $outPath -Container $containerName -Blob $huntingQueryFileName  -Context $storageContext -Force

$newHuntingRules = Get-Content -Path "$outPath\$huntingQueryFileName" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

**Facing the below error:**

> WARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 2

Comment: What is the relation between the code and the json? Is the json stored in `"$outPath$huntingQueryFileName"`? The Warning you post usually only happens when you use `ConvertTo-Json`, not `ConvertFrom-Json`...

Comment: Hi Mathias stored the json in this storage account container path "$outPath$huntingQueryFileName" . Trying to fetch the json and retrieving the values from this json

Comment: And do you see the warning already when you call `Get-AzStorageBlobContent`? Or is it the last statement that generates the warning?

Comment: `convertto-json -depth 100`

Comment: Hi Mathias.. It is working for me now with no json issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*****I executed below script in my environment and was able to successfully retrieve the expected content (from json format)*****.

```
$path = "C:\temp"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "jahnavistorage" -StorageAccountKey "<storageaccountkey>=="
Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "<containerName>" -Blob "myjson.json" -Destination $path -context $context
Get-ChildItem -path $path
Get-Content -Raw $path\myjson.json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Jahnavi .. It worked for me.. Thanks a lot . Can you please look into this query ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75136560/can-we-call-a-runbook-from-another-runbook-in-powershell/75142119#75142119